# What terms should I use to define security assessment work?

Tags: terminology, outsourcing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a penetration test and a vulnerability assessment?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2837/what-is-the-difference-between-a-penetration-test-and-a-vulnerability-assessment)

I am tasked with hiring a consultant to do an analysis of our infrastructure security for a one-time projected based contract.  I would like to know if there is a known term for this type of work that I should be using when looking for this type of service, and if there are any references one might use to build a request for proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Infrastructure Security Assessments