# What is Penetration Testing?

Tags: penetration-test

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a penetration test and a vulnerability assessment?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2837/what-is-the-difference-between-a-penetration-test-and-a-vulnerability-assessment)

What is Penetration Testing? When a security professional throws around these words, what do they mean by them?