# What is a fair fee to pay for a Penetration tester in the USA?

Tags: attacks

What is a fair fee to pay for a Penetration tester in USA to test a website running on PHP, linux, MySql and make recommendations for fixes?

The site has thousands of pages and is running a YouTube Clone script and some WordPress scripts and is similar to a site like this one:
epinions.com

Comment: This question is quite vague so it will likely get closed. FWIW, first develop a detailed requirements document and determine if you need a [Vulnerability Scan or a Penetration Test](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2837/what-is-the-difference-between-a-penetration-test-and-a-vulnerability-assessment). Then shop around. The more detail you can provide in the requirements doc the more accurate the estimate will be.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends.

There are some flat rate companies that charge by the size and scope of the project (i.e., 10 public webservers, 10 internal servers, 3 firewalls, 1 domain, 100 users, etc. = $X)

Then there are some companies that charge by T&M (time and materials). In which case, the longer the project goes on, the more it costs.

We tend to do fixed fee assessments because we know how long a project should take for a given size. But again, it all depends on the size of the environment. *For example, Netflix (in the US anyway) maybe just one site, but may be powered by thousands of servers, a huge infrastructure footprint, etc.*

**Recommendation**

Get a few quotes from some trusted vendors/consultants and pick the one that works best for your comfort level and budget.